# Generate Facebook access token with ads_read

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-ads-api

I want to get Facebook statistics about campaigns and ads using the Facebook Ads API (https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-ads-sdk).

I have created an app (with ID and secret), added the Marketing API and now I can generate an access token with the `ads_read` permission, which is valid for 2 month.

Is there any way that I can avoid the process of manually clicking that button every other month?

I have tried this call:

`$tokenUrl = 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/oauth/access_token?client_id=' . $app_id . '&client_secret=' . $app_secret . '&grant_type=client_credentials&scope=ads_read';`

This gives me an access token that look something like this: `680012345678976|aIDrLVvFqHXDzl6538RLUF4S9C4` and it doesn't work (Unsupported get request).

The manually generated token is 164 chars long.

Comment: This is super frustrating. Same issue. I have to create a token which has an associated USER, which is ME (because that's what you are supposed to do). But that means if I log out of Facebook, when testing Facebook Login for my website then it breaks the SERVER SIDE access token for Marketing API. Am I supposed to make a fake user?

Comment: Also I'm not seeing an expiration of 2 months. I see `Never`. Are you still having this expiration issue?

Comment: What I ended up doing was creating a new app for just marketing API (instead of Facebook Login Button + Marketing API). Had to go through all the authorizations again with Facebook. Now I have a token that apparently should last forever.

Answer (score 2):

What I did was:

1.Call

```
https://www.facebook.com/v2.8/dialog/oauth?client_id=
<APP_ID>&redirect_uri=<REDIRECT_URI>&scope=ads_read
```

then after clicking "Allow", I would get redirected to

```
<REDIRECT_URI>/?code=<AUTHORIZED_CODE>
```

2.Exchange the authorized code for access token

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/oauth/access_token?client_id=<APP_ID>&redirect_uri=<REDIRECT_URI>&client_secret=<CLIENT_SECRET>&code=<AUTHORIZED_CODE>
```

your redirect uri should ends with / e.g. http://localhost:3000/

I tried this by manually copied and pasted in a browser, but automate request/response should give the same result.

Reference: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/access

Comment: Note: This is still associated with a user. So if that user associates and deassociates with the app, which could be during testing of 'Facebook Login' for your website - then that access token is null and voided.

Comment: You can also verify the 'owner' of the final token here https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken/

Comment: I suppose this means you should create a separate server side and client side app if you're accessing `ads_read` on server side.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the short living token for a long living one (even without expiration) by doing a request from your server

```
GET https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?  
   grant_type=fb_exchange_token&         
   client_id={app-id}&
   client_secret={app-secret}&
   fb_exchange_token={short-lived-token}
```

Note that even the token that is set to never expire can be invalidated by user, for example if he changes FB password or removes your app entirely.

For more details refer to [the docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/expiration-and-extension)

Comment: It doesn't seem to work: `No user access token specified`

Comment: Short-lived tokens expire in about two hours. If you have a token that expires in 60 days, that __is__ an extended/long-lived token already.

Comment: No. I still believe the answer is correct, since I use this request to exchange login tokens for tokens with "Expiration: Never". I did the request by hand now just to check and it does work as expected.
@allanth, did you try doing the request using some REST client, outside PHP, without FB SDK?

Comment: @David, I tried it in the browser. It was the wrong kind of access token. Very confusing. Anyway, I don't really care about the expiration. I'm more interested in getting/generating the token programmatically if possible.

Comment: @David, can you tell more about this.? I am able to fetch access token for 60 days but I want to extend that also because I want to download user ads insights with access token via cron.